# how to change character_set_client and character_set_results by client coding instead of changing my.ini

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I have a requirement that change `character_set_client` and `character_set_results`, but don't wanna change them in `my.ini`, currently on client code side we have a connection configuration as below: `username:password@tcp(dns_ip:PORT)/db_name?timeout=10s&readTimeout=10s`,

so anyone knows how to change `character_set_client` and `character_set_results` by changing above configuration? thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `collation=utf8mb4_general_ci` can work